# How to know which Outlook Calendar item was deleted?

Tags: c#, outlook

The following code alerts when new Outlook Calendar items are created and/or deleted:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var oApp = new Application();
    var mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    var CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    var outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
    outlookCalendarItems.ItemAdd += item => Console.WriteLine($"Created: {(item as AppointmentItem).Subject}");
    outlookCalendarItems.ItemRemove += () => Console.WriteLine($"Removed: ...?");

    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The problem is that `outlookCalendarItems.ItemRemove` doesn't provide the actual item that was deleted...

How can I know which item was deleted (e.g. tell its subject)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event fires asynchronously so by the time the `ItemRemove` event fires, the item is already gone.  Even on the MAPI level, when the folder contents table fires the `fnevTableModified | TABLE_ROW_DELETED` notification, it only provides the value of the `PR_INSTANCE_KEY` property (you can see it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) (I am its author) - click IMAPIFolder, go to the GetContentsTable table, see the log at the bottom of the page when you delete an item).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am also its author), you can use [RDOItems](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOItems.htm).`ItemRemove` event - it does pass the value of `PR_INSTANCE_KEY` as the parameter.

`PR_INSTANCE_KEY` is useful only if you have already cached the value of that property for all items in the folder, or at least of the items that you are interested in. Keep in mind that [PR_INSTANCE_KEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765693%28v=office.15%29.aspx) cannot be cached between sessions - it is only valid for a particular instance of the contents table (`IMAPITable`).

Also keep in mind that all items events are designed for the UI purposes only, they should not be used for any kind of synchronization - they can be and are dropped under heavy loads.

If you use the event for synchronization, your options are either to use `ItemRemove` event as a hint that your sync must run sooner rather than later and loop through all items in a store to figure out which item changed, or, in case of Exchange, you can use the Incremental Change Synchronization API (ICS). It is exposed as the [RDOFolderSynchronizer](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdofoldersynchronizer.htm) object in Redemption.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So my choice is either install a 3rd-party tool ("Redemption") or run whole re-sync?

Comment: Yes. Or use Extended MAPI in C++ or Delphi.

Comment: I couldn't find the license of Redemption - do you possibly have a reference to it?

Comment: Do you mean the EULA? It is is at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/EULA_Redemption_Eval.htm. The distributable version EULA is at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/EULA_Redemption_Dist.htm